# Delete Function: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1GB exhausted (tried to allocate 64 bytes) dbo_mysql.php on line 779 (CakePHP)

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, memory-leaks, fatal-error

I'm trying to use the "delete user" function on the back-end of my website but I keep on receiving this **Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1GB exhausted (tried to allocate 64 bytes) dbo_mysql.php on line 779** error.

I set my **memory_limit** to 1GB; which should be more than enough, and I still have the same issue.

The strange part is I have the same exact setup on my "**test site**" and it works fine there.

Both my "**test**" and "**live**" site are on the same server, same PHP settings, same MySQL settings, same PHP code, etc. and for some reason this doesn't work on my "**live site**".

The only difference between these sites is my "**live site**" has a larger database but nothing crazy; total MySQL database is probably only 250MB on my "**live site**".

Does anyone have an idea of why I'm having this issue on my "**live site**" only?  What's the best way to debug this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Nobody here will be able to properly answer your question, as nobody knows anything about the code that you are using, the structure of your database, etc. All people can do here is guessing, which isn't overly helpful. I would suggest that you start with some debugging, for example use a profiler to check where exactly the memory leak is located.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I'm not familiar with the best ways to debug this issue.  I see you mentioned to use a profiler, how exactly would I use a profiler? Ty.

Comment: Hard to help you without knowing the tools you are using. Or the commands you're executing.